# In a migration, how do you change the column type to text without specifying the :limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I want to change a column type from `:string` to `:text`

The problem is that if I simply do:

```
change_column :questions, :content, :text
```

Then the schema is rewritten to:

```
t.string   "content",     :limit => 255
```

i.e. it takes the length that was implicit when it was a `string`

How can I do the migration and specify that the `:limit` should not be set such that the schema reads:

```
t.string   "content"
```

I have tried setting an arbitrary limit of 10,000 but a) that feels inefficient and b) it makes the down migration attempt to set the `:text` limit to 10,000.

What option can I pass to the `change_column` method to ensure it simply uses the default limit?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ack, discovered this by trial and error moments after posting the question:

```
change_column :questions, :content, :text, :limit => nil
```